# UITextView disable word wrap

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I want to display the response of a web request which is an unknown length.
I have chosen to use a scrollable UITextView, however it seems to automatically word wrap which doesn't look too great.
I dont think UITextView has a way of disabling this word wrapping.

What would be a better option do display an unknown number of characters on an unknown number of lines?

Thanks

Comment: What about it "doesn't look too great?"  Is this response human-readable, or more like URL/XML/SQL/something else that is easier for computers to read than humans?

Comment: It depends what command is sent. There's hundreds of possible responses, some of them are like command line table views, where the first line has some headers, second line will have an underline etc.. They appear fine in the console, but when wrapped into a small window look awful. Horizontal scrolling would be better.

Comment: Then I'd suggest a simple UIView subclass. Once you get your string back, determine an appropriate size for the view, use your favorite drawing methods/functions to draw the string onto the view, and then put the view in a UIScrollView with appropriate content size.

Comment: I dint suppose you've got any code for determining the size from a string?

Comment: Sure do: CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(99999999, myView.frame.size.height); CGSize reqSize = [myStrOutput sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12] constrainedToSize:maxSize]; Then you can go use the reqSize.width or reqSize.height as you see fit. You just got to make sure your view that will display the text uses the same UIFont type and size.

Comment: Zhang is exactly right, although I'd suggest Courier since (A) you might need to present text-based tables, and you probably want a mono-spaced font for those, and (B) I don't like Ariel. :)  If you like this as a solution, I'll post it as an answer for you.

Comment: Thanks I've got this half working without subclassing. I've put a UITextView inside a UIScrollView and use this code:
CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(9999999999, 9999999999);
    CGSize reqSize = [responce sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size:14] constrainedToSize:maxSize];
    
    self.responceTextView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, reqSize.width, reqSize.height);
    self.responceTextView.text = responce;
    self.responceScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.responceTextView.frame.size.width, self.responceTextView.frame.size.height); However sometimes the width and height isn't right

Comment: With some responses, the size and scroll is perfect, however sometimes it can cut several lines off, or be to narrow.

Comment: Reading the docs for sizeWithFont, it seems that it can word-wrap if it thinks it's necessary which I dont want. I've tried sizeWithFont:contrainedToSize:lineBreakMode but each line break setting doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I got it working with the above code, but I had to add 16px padding onto the width and height. Thanks for the help. Especially the advice to use mono-spaced font. Thanks